# How to use the zoom gesture in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I found the example code for the `GestureListener` class, but I don't understand the zoom method:

```
private float initialScale = 1;

public boolean zoom (float originalDistance, float currentDistance) {
    float ratio = originalDistance / currentDistance; //I get this
    camera.zoom = initialScale * ratio; //This doesn't make sense to me because it seems like every time you pinch to zoom, it resets to the original zoom which is 1. So basically it wouldn't 'save' the zoom right?
    System.out.println(camera.zoom); //Prints the camera zoom
    return false;
}
```

Am I not interpreting this right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be camera.zoom ×= ratio; ?

Comment: I think this interface and the GestureDetector class is not very well thought through. I'm having the same problem, and I'm now trying to figure out a good solution.

Comment: I think the interface would need a `zoomStart(float distance)` and a `zoomStop(float initialDistance, float finalDistance)` method

Answer (score 1):

Each time you put your fingers on the screen the `originalDistance / currentDistance` will result in the value 1.

If you use this value directly the zoom would always start at zoom = 1.0f.

To solve this issue you should store the current zoom factor at the start of the zoom and multiply this with the new calculated ratio. 
So: on touchDown take the current zoom: `initialScale = Camara.zoom;`.

Answer (score 0):

`initialScale` looks like a constant used to scale everything in the game.

`zoom` function calculates `originalDistance / currentDistance` value, applies it to Camera and prints it out.

It's hard to tell more without seeing other affected code.